# regex replace text between tags <script language='javascript'> and </script>

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace, tags

I cant find a working demo on StackOverflow or Google of this.
I have a string, which contains an area I need to remove.

```
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script language='javascript'>
//Lots of javascript here
</script>
```

I need help removing all the text between `<script language='javascript'>` and `<script>` please, including the tages itself.
I have attempted

```
  Dim str As String = Regex.Replace(mystring,"\<script language='javascript'>(.*?)\</script>", "")
```

Closest I got to finding something was this
[Regular expression to replace text before </script> tag or between text in script tag in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049167/regular-expression-to-replace-text-before-script-tag-or-between-text-in-scrip)
but no cigar unfortunately

Comment: [Don't parse html with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) Use dom parser.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for an XML parser:

```
Dim xm = New XmlDocument()
xm.LoadXml(String.Format("{0}", str))
Dim scripts = xm.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("script")
For Each s In scripts
    xm.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(s)
Next
str = xm.DocumentElement.InnerXml
```

This removes all script tags, along with their contents.

Answer (score 1):

It's a job for HTML parser. By using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/&ei=wAi_ULjBD4Wl4gTUpYHQBw&usg=AFQjCNG2MH29eft1y8OrwFMjVzPNbVc0-w&sig2=Qbz6s0OjLEVK9XsBDs5sdQ):

```
Dim doc = New HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(html)
Dim scriptNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script[@language='javascript']").ToList()

For Each scriptNode As HtmlNode In scriptNodes
    scriptNode.InnerHtml = String.Empty
Next

Dim result = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml
```

This selects `script` nodes with `language` attribute
set to `javascript`, and then removes the content of these nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should do what you want.

```
/<script.*>([\s\S]*)</script>/m
```

Explanation:
the [\s\S] group matches all characters where the '.' matches all characters -except- newlines. And we want newlines.

The /m makes the regex multiline so it matches across multiple lines instead of just one.

That being said: i just answered the question you just asked (how do to it with a regexp), but I do however agree that you should use a dom parser for this since its more resilient. (But then again, this regexp might be faster performance wise.)